# Double integral of an off origin circle

Tags: integration

The question was $$\iint_\mathcal{D}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,dx\,dy$$ with $\mathcal{D}=\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2\leq2x\}.$

I plotted $\mathcal{D}$ and found out that it was a circle of radius $1$ at the point $(1,0)$, so it's considered off origin.

I tried to use polar coordinate to solve the problem by moving the circle to the origin but the answer seems wrong.

Also, the Cartesian method of double integration give very big number and cannot undergo further integration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The circle is more special than just "off origin."  It's tangent to the $y$-axis at the origin.  Its polar equation is $r=2\cos \theta$, as $-\pi/2 < \theta <\pi/2$.  The polar integral is

$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_0^{2\cos \theta} r^2 \; dr \; d\theta. $$

Answer (score 1):

You can't just move the region D. You would have to shift the surface, too. Hint: Use $r=2\cos\theta$ for boundary of D.